# Can I put a bounty on a question where I have answered and award the bounty to my answer?

Tags: support, bounty

Can I put a bounty on a question where I have answered and award the bounty to my answer as an exemplary answer? Moreover does the author of the question have anything to say on whom I decide to award the bounty?

Comment: Glad you asked before trying this. If this were possible it would allow free advertising. Bounties are meant to be used for altruistic reasons only.  This aspect (increased exposure) explains why the minimum amount is raised to 100 points, if you have answered the question yourself.

Comment: To elaborate on @Jyrki's point, some users used to answer a question and then put a bounty of 50 points on it. Then due to the increased exposure they got lots of upvote on their answer (more than 5), resulting in a net gain of reputation. This was seen as gaming the system, and this is why 1/ the min amount is now 100 for questions you have answered 2/ the min amount increases for each new bounty (because you used to be able to do that an unlimited amount of times, basically).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I put a bounty on a question where I have answered

Yes, you can, but for questions you have answered, the minimum bounty value is 100, rather than the general 50.

> and award the bounty to my answer as an exemplary answer?

No, you can't do that. Awarding a bounty to oneself would be kind of pointless, wouldn't it?

> Moreover does the author of the question have anything to say on whom I decide to award the bounty?

No, within the restrictions of the system, you alone decide which answer the bounty is awarded to - unless you let the bounty period and grace period pass without awarding the bounty, then the system may award half of the bounty automatically (if there is an answer eligible for automatic awards).

Comment: A little known clause gives the author some say in cases when the bounty setter fails to award it. If they accept an eligible answer during the bounty period, that answer gets the full amount of bounty. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: It says "If _the bounty starter_ accepted an answer during the bounty period", I interpret it so that only if the question author started the bounty an accept causes the full bounty to be awarded.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that clause. It somehow made more sense for me the other way.